# How may i make the best of 3 flaky connections?

Tags: ip, bonding

i have 2 access providers.  Neither is stable.  Either connection may go dead for seconds or hours at a time.  When "working", both connections are likely to drop anywhere from 0-100% of packets.

And i have 2 physical machines, an e540 laptop with 8g ram and an elitedesk 800 g3 with 24g ram, each has a wire to the modem for provider #1 and wifi to the modem for provider #2.  Both wifi connections are independently flaky, in addition to the underlying providers being flaky.  The wired connections are usually better, but not reliably so.

What configuration approach will make the best of this situation?  Does load balancing imply good failover capability or does it presume multiple reliable connections?  Does failover make good use of continuously intermittent connections?

Network teaming is deprecated in rhel9.  My uninformed guess is that reflects newer kernel bonding capabilities.

From what i've gathered so far i'm guessing i'll want to configure bonding, hoping to do the best possible with the constantly varying conditions.  i want each box to make the best of its wired connection to provider #1, it's wifi connection to provider #2, and either the before-bonding connections or the after-bonding connection forwarded from the other box.

i regularly use http/https, zoom/jit.si, ipsec/l2tp, and ssh, and understand they are quite differently affected.  Remaking connections is a bother but better than waiting for a connection that's gone dead.

i am biased against GUIs or NetworkManager but will use whatever does the best job.  i prefer manjaro but will consider k/l/xubuntu or alma/rocky/vzlinux/rhel/stream/fedora or even others if there's a good reason.

Comment: What is sure is that bonding/teaming (they can be considered the same) is for L2 (LAN) kind of connectivity. It can't solve this ["poor man's" multi-homed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming#Multihoming_with_multiple_addresses) case. "for outgoing traffic, a technique such as **source-specific routing** must be used to route packets through the correct provider, and **reasonable source address selection policies** must be implemented by hosts."

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at pfsense and squid?

pfsense will allow you to setup multiple wan connections for load balancing.

Comment: Does load balancing imply good failover capability? Or does it presume fairly reliable connections while they are "up"?  Is pfsense basically a gui exposing BSD network cability or is pfsense implementing the load balancing?  And how does that compare with what recent linux kernels offer?  Any further elaboration would be great...